# MySQL: Get latest message grouped by recipient's mobile number

Tags: mysql

I have a series of SMS messages I got from a dump and am planning on arranging it so each row only displays the latest message in each thread. I'm having problems writing this query but essentially since the Sender is always the same number (`gateway number`) then it would be best to group it by the Recipient (`groupby number`).

I can imagine this like email where the latest message being displayed can either be from the Sender or the Recipient (whichever is latest) but nonetheless grouped by the Recipient. Honestly, I don't know how to go about this.

**Messages table.** Type `out` means `gateway` sent it, `in` means `groupby` sent it.

```
|  id  |  groupby  |  gateway  |  message    |  type  |  created              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |  +111     |  +789     |  Hello      |  out   |  2015-01-01 00:00:00  |
|  2   |  +222     |  +789     |  World      |  out   |  2015-01-02 00:00:00  |
|  3   |  +111     |  +789     |  What's     |  in    |  2015-01-03 00:00:00  |
|  4   |  +222     |  +789     |  New        |  in    |  2015-01-04 00:00:00  |
|  5   |  +111     |  +789     |  With You?  |  out   |  2015-01-05 00:00:00  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the result should be:

**Result in html.**

```
|  id  |  groupby  |  message    |  sent from  |
------------------------------------------------
|  5   |  +111     |  With You?  |  +789       |
|  4   |  +222     |  New        |  +222       |
------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in many ways and one is

```
select 
m.* from messages m
join(
 select
 groupby,
 max(created) as created
 from messages group by groupby
)m1
on m1.groupby = m.groupby and m1.created = m.created
```

Comment: In the subquery, is it faster to use `MAX(id) AS id` instead of `MAX(created)` since `id` would most likely be __INT__ (although I didn't specify it). In the outer query that would make it `AND m1.id = m.id`.

Comment: Yeah id is primary key and it would be faster however if created is indexed then you are likely to have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, `groupby`, message, 
(CASE WHEN typo='out' THEN `groupby` ELSE gateway END) AS sentfrom 
FROM __table__name  
GROUP BY sentfrom ORDER BY created DESC;
```